# Kali - Where do installed programs go?

Tags: linux

I'm a relatively new user of Kali Linux. I've installed `tor-arm` using `apt-get install tor-arm` and everything went OK.

I can't figure out where this installation went though. I've had this problem in general when using Kali (or Linux in general?). The Desktop Search doesn't yield any results for `tor-arm` even though I know it's installed somewhere.

**What is the path where these installs go?**

(Note: Typing `tor-arm` or `./tor-arm` in a terminal says no command/file/directory match)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in any Debian-based distro, executable files go into `/usr/bin`, resources into `/usr/share`, config files into `/etc` and logs into `/var/logs`. Check the [directory structure](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard) for further info.

You can use Synaptic Package manager to look into package installed files. To launch Synaptic, use these commands in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
sudo synaptic
```